# Plot the difference between two lists of values in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, matplotlib, statistics

I have two datetime based lists.  I want to plot the difference between their values.

The problem is, the lists are of different lengths / resolutions.

For example:

- list 1 is a list of readings taken every minute throughout the day.
- list 2 is a list of readings taken *randomly* throughout the day.

I can plot the two graphs using matplotlib like so:

[image: Two wiggly lines on a graph]

What I want to do is plot the *difference* between these two lines.

Here's some example data

```
x1 = ["12:01", "12:02", "12:03", ..., "13:00"]
y1 = [2,       6,       7,       ..., 9]
x2 = ["12:01", "12:12", "12:14", ..., "12:59"]
y2 = [3,       -5,       7,      ..., 0]
plt.plot(x1,  y1)
plt.plot(x2,  y2)
```

The real X values are `datetime.datetime` objects.

I can't just do `y1 - y2` - because x1 & y1 are different lengths from x2 & y2.

Is there a way to calculate the difference between the drawn graph lines at, say, every five minutes and have that drawn?

Comment: You need to interpolate the data, such that both time series share a common base. `numpy.unique`, `numpy.argsort`, `numpy.interp` will probably be helpful. The datetimes would first need to be converted to a numeric format.

Comment: You could use `pandas`, [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.resample.html) the time series and use something like `ffill` to fill the missing values before computing the difference. Depends the approximation you can tolerate.

Comment: Thanks @FabienP - that's just what I was looking for.